# Nuget package How to only add app setting to config if it's doesn't already exist?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I have created some basic Nuget packages to add database specific items to our projects. Part of the package adds a connection string to the app/web.config file.

I've read thru the nuget package creation documentation but have not been able to figure out how to set up the Transforms to only add the connection string, or other app settings, if it doesn't already exist.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key was doing the transforms in app.config.install.xdt files not in the app.config.transform files.

Comment: Hi friend, thanks for sharing the useful info and please mark it as answer which will help other community members who easier search this useful information, it just a reminder :)